# Set size of vector of vectors at run time

Tags: c++, vector, initialization

I would like to know, how to set the size of vector of vectors at run time.

If I have fixed size, i usually do it by

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> ref(5);
```

and i push the elements in the specific vector by

```
ref[i].push_back(23); // i = 0,1,...4
```

Now if am interested to set the size at run time, means, i want to get size through command line argument, and push the elements in the same way as above.

I thought to do it by declaring the vector of vectors by keeping it open

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> ref;
```

and then push the element

```
ref[i].push_back(23);
```

But I am sure to be wrong, as I get the error

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: Initialize the vector std::vector<std::vector<int>> ref{{}}

Comment: Is for something special that you want to set the size ?

Comment: Just a small comment i = 1..5, ref[i] will segfault, indexing are starting from zero in C++ so the range of i have to be 0..4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `std::vector::resize`. It increases the capacity of the vector if input size is greater that current size of vector without changing the content of the vector. (It may reallocate the vector, but that doesn't effect your program)

Initialize the vector as you did:
`vector<vector<int> > ref;`

Now, when ever you push back, check if `i` is within current size of vector. If not, resize the `std::vector` and then call `std::vector::push_back`

```
if(i>=ref.size())
    ref.resize(i);
ref[i].push_back(23);
```

Answer (score 3):

> I want to get size through command line argument, and push the elements in the same way as above.

Ask the user for the max size before asking for `i`:

```
cout << "What is the size of your vector? ";
int size;
cin >> size;
std::vector<std::vector<int>> ref(size);
```

Now you can ask for `i`, check them against `size`, and then call `ref[i]` without a crash.

Comment: Why is `std::vector<std::vector<int>> ref(size);`  allowed ? why is there no need for allocating dynamically? Can you please explain or link me to suitable questions.

Answer (score 0):

You were going well keeping it open, you only forget the initialization.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> ref{{}}
```

Edit: Of course, if you want ref to grow you also need to pushback vectors in it:

```
std::vector<int> v1;
ref.push_back(v1);
```

then,

```
ref[1][0]=23.
```

Comment: It works for only one vector ref[0] , after that  `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc`.

Comment: The solution I proposed is not magic. You can make ref grow without having to set its size -as the last part of the question proposed-, but of course you need to add the necessary push_back's.